# Ошибка NullPointerException

Tags: java

Следующий код при запуске выдает ошибку. Помогите разобраться, в чем проблема и как ее решить?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem bold;
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem underlined;
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem italic;
    private JLabel label;
    public MyFrame()
    {
        setTitle("My Frame");
        setBounds(500,250,500,500);
        Container pane=getContentPane();
        //MyPanel panel=new MyPanel();
        //pane.add(panel);
        /*This is Menu*/

        JMenu menu=new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem FileItem=menu.add("Open Last Menu");
        JMenuItem OpenItem=menu.add("Open File");
        OpenItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        menu.addSeparator();
        JMenuItem CreateItem=menu.add("Create File");
        CreateItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        JMenuItem SaveItem=menu.add("Save File");
        menu.addSeparator();
        JMenuItem ImportItem=menu.add("Import Project");
        JMenuItem PrintItem=menu.add("Print File");
        PrintItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));

        JMenu EditMenu=new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenuItem CancelItem=EditMenu.add("Cancel");
        JMenuItem CutItem=EditMenu.add("Cut");
        EditMenu.addSeparator();
        JMenuItem PasteItem=EditMenu.add("Paste");
        JMenuItem DeleteItem=EditMenu.add("Delete");

        JFrame panel_1=new JFrame();
        panel_1.add ( new JComponent()
        {
            public void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
            {
                super.paintComponent ( g );

                Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
                g2d.setPaint ( Color.BLACK );
                Stroke oldStroke = g2d.getStroke ();
                Stroke newStroke = new BasicStroke ( 2f );
                FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics ();

                //

                g2d.setStroke ( oldStroke );
                g2d.drawRoundRect ( 5, 5, getWidth () / 2 - 10, getHeight () / 2 - 10, 20, 20 );
                String s1 = "1px stroke, AA off";
                g2d.drawString ( s1, getWidth () / 4 - fm.stringWidth ( s1 ) / 2,
                                 getHeight () / 4 + fm.getAscent () / 2 );

                g2d.setStroke ( newStroke );
                g2d.drawRoundRect ( 5, getHeight () / 2 + 5, getWidth () / 2 - 10,
                                    getHeight () / 2 - 10, 20, 20 );
                String s2 = "2px stroke, AA off";
                g2d.drawString ( s2, getWidth () / 4 - fm.stringWidth ( s2 ) / 2,
                                 getHeight () * 3 / 4 + fm.getAscent () / 2 );

                //

                g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                       RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
                g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                                       RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );

                g2d.setStroke ( oldStroke );
                g2d.drawRoundRect ( getWidth () / 2 + 5, 5, getWidth () / 2 - 10,
                                    getHeight () / 2 - 10, 20, 20 );
                String s3 = "1px stroke, AA on";
                g2d.drawString ( s3, getWidth () * 3 / 4 - fm.stringWidth ( s3 ) / 2,
                                 getHeight () / 4 + fm.getAscent () / 2 );

                g2d.setStroke ( newStroke );
                g2d.drawRoundRect ( getWidth () / 2 + 5, getHeight () / 2 + 5, getWidth () / 2 - 10,
                                    getHeight () / 2 - 10, 20, 20 );
                String s4 = "2px stroke, AA on";
                g2d.drawString ( s4, getWidth () * 3 / 4 - fm.stringWidth ( s4 ) / 2,
                                 getHeight () * 3 / 4 + fm.getAscent () / 2 );
            }
        } );
        pane.add(label);
        pane.add(panel_1);
        ActionListener listener=new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                int mode=0;
                if(bold.isSelected()) mode+=Font.BOLD;
                if(italic.isSelected()) mode+=Font.ITALIC;
                label.setFont(new Font("Serif",mode,20));
            }
        };
        ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();
        bold=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Bold");
        bold.setSelected(true);
        bold.addActionListener(listener);
        underlined=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Underlined");
        underlined.addActionListener(listener);
        italic=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Italic");
        italic.addActionListener(listener);
        group.add(bold);
        group.add(underlined);
        group.add(italic);
        EditMenu.addSeparator();
        JMenu AlignMenu=new JMenu("Align");
        AlignMenu.add(bold);
        AlignMenu.add(underlined);
        AlignMenu.add(italic);
        EditMenu.add(AlignMenu);



        JMenuBar bar=new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(bar);
        bar.add(menu);
        bar.add(EditMenu);


    }
}
/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MyFrame frame=new MyFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.show();
    }

}
```

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1041)
>           at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:365)
>           at this_is_my_project.MyFrame.<init>(Main.java:99)
>           at this_is_my_project.Main.main(Main.java:150)
>   Java Result: 1`

Comment: [В чем ошибка?](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/09/blog-post_24.html)
[Хороший вопрос - залог хорошего ответа](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_8123.html)

Comment: Наверное все-таки ошибка возникает при исполнении, а не компиляции.

В выводе *Exception in thread "main"...* у Вас указаны номера строк
(Main.java:99) и (Main.java:150), Вы хотите, чтобы кто-то за Вас их отсчитывал в приведенном коде ?

Comment: нет конечно... Она иногда возникает.. А где можно по подробней разузнать про ошибку NullPointerException?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте проинициализировать данный `Label` перед тем, как тыкать его на `ContentPane`.

```
private JLabel label;
pane.add(label);
```

А потом разберитесь, почему нельзя вот так просто добавить окно в контейнер:

```
JFrame panel_1=new JFrame();
pane.add(panel_1);
```